# Unable to read settings file error in MavensMate for Sublime Text 3

Tags: mavensmate

This morning seemingly out of the blue I'm unable to perform any actions in the MavensMate IDE.  Every action gives me the following error:

Result: [OPERATION FAILED]: Unable to read settings file for this project.

I could just scrap everything and start from scratch but tying back into github is somewhat tedious and I'd like to be able to address this in the future should it occur again.  I couldn't find anything on Google except the error message condition in the github repo for the project here (lines 902 & 907):
https://github.com/joeferraro/mm/blob/master/mm/project.py

I can't figure out how to action that, though.

Comment: Has anything changed either in MavensMate, Github, or your org?

Comment: Actually - I think I figured this out.  I'm not sure how the settings were corrupted, but one of my branches did not produce the error.  So I switched to master, deleted all of the Mavensmate config files, then converted the project to a Mavensmate project again.  This seems to have resolved it.

Comment: Another note - I think this occurs during branch merges.  I'm still unsure of exactly what causes it.